# Set up separate subdomain for each site language in django

Tags: python, django, subdomain

I want to be able to use subdomains to specify language of the site, just like django-localeurl use url prefix for this purpose. Is there are any non-hacky way to do this?

Comment: Thanx for those who answered. I've wrote the middleware and it works exelent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would suggest writing custom middleware ([Django | Middleware)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request). If you override the `process_request` method, you could determine the url from the HttpRequest object and assign the language accordingly (`request.META.get('SERVER_NAME')`). You could create a dictionary of key (domains)/ value (language) pairs to assign the appropriate one.

Comment: Actually request.META.get('HTTP_HOST') might work better, if you are load balancing or the host is somehow dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same issue, except I allowed users to create their own customizable subdomains.  I solved it by creating a custom middleware.  the `Poster` model would correspond to your language model.  I don't think parsing urls is a trivial task, I use `tldextract` it works excellent. https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

```
from our_jobs.apps.poster.models import Poster
import tldextract


class SubdomainMiddleware:
  """Handle if request is coming from subdomain"""

  def process_request(self, request):
    """Filter the given request"""
    host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '')
    extract = tldextract.extract(host)
    request.poster = None
    if extract.subdomain:
        try:
            request.poster = Poster.objects.get(subdomain=extract.subdomain)
        except Poster.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

This is middleware documentation.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/